# How to add user in Linux with his information

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line

I want to create C application to add user in Linux with `useradd` command .

I write this code when i use it terminal print error message:

```
useradd :permission denied
useradd :cannot lock/etc/passwd; try again later
```

this is my C code to add user such as i want to add `user1` just write user1

```
char a[50];
char command[150];
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
strcpy(command,"useradd ");
strcat(command,a);
```

how i can solve this problem with correct syntax or command?

Comment: How are you invoking your program? Via sudo?

Comment: This is simply a problem of permission. You started your program as a user. User can t add other user, only root can. Try `sudo myapp`, it will make your app run as root, and you ll be able to add a user.

Comment: @Adam i use gcc to compile my program

Comment: @user3602366 invoking as in executing, running etc. Doesn't matter what you compiled with

Comment: Why not use use `useradd` directory from the shell? Why wrap it in a C program?

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I warp with c to make it easy to add/delete user or add user to specific group

Comment: [You should not use `fgets()`](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/fgets.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `sudo` package is not installed, You can install it. Or you can create it as a root using `su` . It will ask root password after that you can use any superuser caommnads.

Comment: i install `sudo` package but when use it the terminal is stop working

Comment: which distro you are using. I think its not sudo problem. after installing you have to modify the content inside `etc/sudoers` which will be in read only mode. first change the permission and then add one line `user ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`. **user should be your system user name**

Comment: after that again you have to change the permission to `-r--r-----` then it will start working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to run the command with root privileges.

Try something like this, sudo -- useradd

Comment: How i use this command correctly please to add password for user i want to add

Comment: First run a command for root access. Second run de useradd command